# omniauth (linkedin) without Device - how to redirect to 'new' with validation messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, linkedin-api

I want users to be able to connect via other services (linked, facebook, google and twitter) without having to fill in another password.

I have been following the amazing 235 & 236 episodes of railscast.com which explain rather nicely how to use OmniAuth with Devise gem.

I am not using Devise which confuses me and I don't manage to get it working as in the videocast.

I tried following Ryan Bates instructions and adapt to my situation. I can't follow his instructions from minute 10 of no236 video where he overrides Devise's registration controller and views.

So my problem happens when no user is signed in and no omniauth authentication available. 
In that case, I need to create a new user, save, sign in and finally redirect.

If the save fails after validation, I need a redirect to user new form with validation errors.

I do manage to redirect to the new user form, BUT I don't manage to get the validation errors.

CODE authentications controller

```
def create
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
  #current_user = find_current_user
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
    flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
    login_and_redirect(authentication.user)
  elsif @current_user 
    @current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  else
    user = User.new
    puts "OmniAuth: " + omniauth[:info].to_s
    user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)

    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      login_and_redirect(user)
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Omniauth Extra."
      session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
      user.valid?
      #redirect_to :controller => :users, :action => :new, :plan => 2
      redirect_to new_user_url
    end
  end 
end
```

QUESTIONS

Question 1: How do I redirect to user new with a pre-filled form using omniauth user info and errors messages?

Question 2: How do I skip validation in my non Devise model when authenticating with another service?

User MODEL

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :authentications
  belongs_to :type, :class_name => "UserType", :foreign_key => "type_id"
  has_many :logins, :class_name => "UserLogin"

  validates :email_address, :email => { :message => 'format is incorrect!' }

  validates_presence_of :email_address, :pseudo, :type_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :email_address, :message => "has already been taken"
  validates_uniqueness_of :pseudo, :message => "has already been taken"

  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  validates_confirmation_of :password

  validate :password_non_blank, :message => "Cannot use blank password!"

  validates :agreed_terms_of_services, :presence => true, :allow_nil => false

  attr_protected :password_hash, :password_salt, :active, :activation_token, :activated_at

  ...

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO resolve Question 1, I created a new method in Authentications controller. I named it new_user_apply_omniauth

```
def new_user_apply_omniauth
  @user = User.new
  @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
  @user.valid?
end
```

Then I copied users NEW view (new.html.erb) and copied it in my new_user_apply_omniauth.html.erb

To answer QUESTION 2, I used conditional validations, watch this excellent railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations